# GPS and directional layer for GPS points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, gpstools

I have millions of GPS location data for some vehicles and a street network for a city.

PROBLEM: 
In an intersection approach, there are points which are entering the intersections and there are other set of points which are leaving the intersection. I want to draw a polygon and clip only those points which are entering the intersection. How this can be done ?
I am thinking of a directional layer which can only capture the points moving in one direction  ?

Comment: Welcome! I would encourage you to update your question with more information about your GPS-points? What data except for the points themselves do you have? object id (car), timestamp (what resolution) etc.. Also do you plan on solving this using ArcGIS only, or are you prepared to and capable of also doing some programming in python?

Answer (score 1):

An approach that you could use, although it will most likely require going outside ArcGIS and into something more flexible (Python / R / Julia etc).

Calculate the distance to the intersection for each point, and then combine this with the timestamp and vehicle ID. Then compare the change in distance between two points in time. If the distance falls between the two points in time, the car is moving towards the intersection.

This can be be scaled to deal with multiple intersections by using only the distance to the nearest intersection, combined with intersection ID (in order to avoid issues right between two intersections).

The actual coding of the above will obviously depend greatly on chosen language so I will not make direct suggestions on that at this point.